# Determine creator of docker volume?

Tags: docker

I have a lot of volumes in Docker that don't have an owner anymore. I'm really curious who keeps creating them, but I cannot figure it out. The volumes are empty inside, so I cannot determine it from their content.

And when I run `docker volume inspect` I get something like this:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-05-17T02:56:30+02:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/storage/docker/volumes/4db244d1741392b730eb4de50ce492ba2b19973aaef51bc5eaa41b4739c246e9/_data",
        "Name": "4db244d1741392b730eb4de50ce492ba2b19973aaef51bc5eaa41b4739c246e9",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

It seems really weird to me that Docker doesn't even record the name of the creator, so am I missing something? How do I track down the previous owner?

Answer (score 1):

As Docker volumes can be shared and used by multiple containers, they get created outside the scope of any container. So it's logical to not keep track of the creator/owner of a volume.

It's actually the container's job to keep track of their own volumes in use.